# Storing user password in Keystore

Tags: encryption, passwords, java

- I am working on an application in which I would like to create a
  keystore with a master password and store user passwords after
  hashing inside it. Is it possible to do so?

  - I am working in Java, so I would appreciate Java based solutions. I
    am also checking how to create keystore in Java code itself.

Currently I have :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

char[] password = "some password".toCharArray();
ks.load(null, password);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newKeyStoreFileName");
ks.store(fos, password);
fos.close();
```

I don't know if it is possible to store Strings in keystore, if not then I am looking to someway store those hashed passwords but encrypted again with a master-password. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No. KeyStores can contains keys and certificates, nothing else. What you're looking for is LDAP or a database with column-hashing features.

Comment: Can you give me some example of how I can achieve that?